# Forecast accuracy metric for forecasts over different time horizons

Tags: forecasting, error

I a dataset of 81 oil price forecasts from more than 30 different forecasters. Those forecasts consist of a forecast made on various days in 2014 for the average oil spot price of 2015. For instance, one forecaster forecasts on the 2nd of January 2014 that the average spot price of oil will be 75 USD/barrel in 2015. Another forecaster forecasts on the 8th of August 2014 that the average spot price of oil in 2015 will be 100 USD/barrel.

If I want to compare the forecast accuracy of those forecasts, it sounds relevant to add a time correction factor, because I want to compare the accuracy of forecasts made over different forecasting horizons. They try to forecast the same (the average oil spot price in 2015), but a forecast made on the 1st of January 2014 (1 year in advance to the 1st of January 2015) compared to a forecast of the 1st of July 2014 (6 months in advance to the 1st of January 2015) should be treated differently in terms of the forecast error. The later the forecast is made, in principle, the larger the advantage, because in general it should already incorporate more information.

Is there a method to compare those forecast errors? General forecast accuracy metrics like RMSE,MAE, MSE, MASE, MAPE,... are used to compare forecasts over the same time horizon. Those metrics are not useful for this case, I suppose?

Comment: Interesting question. I took the liberty of cutting it a bit, which may help you get better answers. Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to determine whether one forecaster is systematically better than another one, or one is better for short-range, but another one is better for long-range forecasts? With only 81 forecasts, you could in fact edit your question to include your actual data, which would help us answer.

Comment: You'd need a way to normalize the prediction errors from the standard metrics by the forecast date. Maybe one way to proceed is to develop a benchmark model from which you obtain benchmark MSPE at each prediction date. Then compute all the MSPE for the variety of forecasting methods and divide by the benchmark MSPE at this date. You'll be able to interpret the results as performance with respect to benchmark levels.